# Parametric Weighted Graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a weighted directed graph with edge-weights given by linear functions $f_i(x) = ax-b$, $0 < a < 1$, $b > 0$. For a given starting parameter $x_0$, a path from $v_i$ to $v_j$ across edges $e_0, e_1, e_2, ... e_n$ is given a cost of $x_0 - f_n(f_{n-1}(...(f_1(f_0(x_0)))...))$. The problem is to find the center of the graph - the node with the minimal cost to reach any other node.

As an example of this problem, consider a vehicle traversing roads between cities. The vehicle has very poor gas mileage per weight of fuel, so that $x$ represents fuel remaining, and $f_i(x)$ represents the remaining fuel in the tank after traversing the road with $x$ amount of fuel in the tank to start with. The goal is to determine which starting city would allow the smallest possible amount of fuel in the tank to start with.

The only way I can think of is exhaustively testing each node to find the smallest $x_0$ which would reach all other nodes on the graph, and then select the node with the smallest $x_0$. Is there a faster way?

Comment: This paper: "Two-phase algorithms for the parametric shortest path problem", link: http://www.cmi.ac.in/~sourav/papers/parametric-sp.pdf might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an [all-pairs shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) problem. I guess there isn't a non-exhaustive way to solve it. The complexity is around $O(|V|^3)$.

Comment: This sounds pretty likely, thanks!